# Why is Visual Studio 2013 not willing to run my Web Performance / Load Test?

Tags: load-testing, visualstudio

I am attempting to run a simple Web Performance Test that I recorded in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.
[image: Run Load Test' icon]

I click the 'Run Load Test' icon inside of VS, only to be greeted with the following error details:

> An unexpected error occurred. Please close this page and re-open it using Load Test Manager, available in the Load Test menu.
>   Failed to queue test run [test name] The active test settings is configured to run test using Visual Studio Online. Connect to a Visual Studio Online account using Team Explorer and try again.

I then click on Load Test > Load Test Manager, only to receive another error:

> The action you are trying to perform requires a connection to Visual Studio Online. Connect to a Visual Studio Online account using Team Explorer and try again.

Thing is, I just want to run my test on the local network; I don't want to use cloud-based testing right now.

What am I doing wrong? Where can I change my active test settings *not* to use Visual Studio Online?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [Visual Studio: Load testing in the cloud](http://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/load-test-your-app-vs), here are the steps to switch the test from using Visual Studio Online to running locally:

1. Simply open your existing project using Visual Studio 2013 first.
2. Within the Solution Explorer, expand the 'Solution Items' folder, then open Local.testsettings.
3. Edit the test settings file to configure your project to run your tests on the local computer.

[image: Choose to run your load tests locally]

Answer (score 3):

You can have more than one ".testsettings" file. On a recent project we used three

- Local.testsettings - for test development and low load tests driven entirely from one computer.
- Agent.testsettings - for testing with a controller plus two agents, for bigger loads.
- Cloud.testsettings - for running tests on Visual Studio Online.

To switch between the three files use the context (right click) menu in solution explorer and "tick" the "Active load and web test settings" entry.

Comment: Ooooooh, "rightclick".  Thanks for this!  I don't know how I overlooked it but I looked for that switch all over the place.  I guess this is a global setting and you can't vary it by load test or load test project.